# Creating a uri from a string, over encoding

Tags: java, url, uri, encode

I'm parsing some links on a webpage and then testing if these links exist or not. I am converting the parsed link strings into uri's, the problem is some of the links already have encoded characters like the following: http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/3/c/63c1d527-9d7e-4fd6-9867-fd0632066740/kinect_qsg%20premium_bndl_en-fr-es.pdf

Which when passed through my code below I get: http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/3/c/63c1d527-9d7e-4fd6-9867-fd0632066740/kinect_qsg%2520premium_bndl_en-fr-es.pdf

Which as you can see is encoding the %20. How do I avoid this? Should I decode my string's first? And if so what's the best way to do this?

```
URL url = null;
        URI uri = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(checkUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getAuthority(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Use URLEncoder and decoder classes

Comment: Why not use [URL.toURI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#toURI%28%29)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using URLDecoder class,

```
        URL url = null;
        URI uri = null;
        String checkUrl = "http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/3/c/63c1d527-9d7e-4fd6-9867-fd0632066740/kinect_qsg%20premium_bndl_en-fr-es.pdf"; 
        try {
            url = new URL(URLDecoder.decode(checkUrl,"UTF-8"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getAuthority(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
            System.out.println(uri.getHost());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The class path for the class is java.net.URLDecoder

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
String decoded = URLDecoder.decode(yorUrl, "UTF-8");
```